# My Minecraft launcher won't open!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My Minecraft launcher isn't opening and every time I try to open the launcher the loading sign pops up next to my mouse for half of a second then goes away leaving nothing.

I have tried everything I know, I have uninstalled then reinstalled *multiple* times, I have gone into the .minecraft files and tried everything I know.

Can anyone tell me how to fix my launcher? If you could I would *really* appreciate it!

**Thank you** to anyone that helped or at least tried to help me with this!!!

Comment: Try updating your java libraries. It could be a outdated java version.

Comment: Your question was closed as unclear.  That's because you haven't provided enough information in order to allow us to help you.  If you want this reopened, I'd suggest adding way more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try re-installing the Minecraft Launcher from [Minecraft.net download page](https://minecraft.net/en-us/download/alternative). First download the installer (The first one on the list), if it doesn't work, download the second one on the list.

Comment: Thanks!! this worked for me!! Thanks so much I really appreciate it! I really love my Minecraft so when this worked I was so happy.

Comment: this didnt work for me.

Comment: @MarkDeven You could try deleting `assets`, `launcher`, `launcher_profiles.json`, `libraries`, `usercache.json` but before that do you see anything suspicious in `nativelog.txt`?

Comment: A full restart including taking out the battery) finally fixed it, so it must have been something in my deep system. IDK.

Answer (score -1):

try reinstalling the launcher if you haven't.
Update the java runtime from *[here](https://www.java.com/en/download/)* if that doesnt work uninstall and reinstall the runtime. if that doesnt work you should see if you have a java home path in your system. this can sometimes help identifying where java applications should find the runtime library. there is a tutorial on how to do this *[here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html)*
let me know how it all went and happy gaming ;)